# How to set Application-UUID for Applications executed from ESL

Tags: freeswitch

I would like to know the triggering ExecuteApplication call for each CHANNEL_EXECUTE event. In Managed ESL's ExecuteAsync method there is no parameter supporting this. The signature is:

```
public ESLevent ExecuteAsync(string app, string arg, string uuid)
```

When an app is started with this ExecuteAsync FreeSwitch generates an UUID for the application and this will be present in all subsequent CHANNEL_EXECUTE event's Application-UUID header field. The problem is that the ExecuteAsynch call doesn't return this UUID. This makes it tricky to track the CHANNEL_EXECUTE events if there are multiple running applications. The event returned by ExecuteAsynch has the following form (no UUID is present):

```
{  
    "Event-Name": "SOCKET_DATA",
    "Content-Type": "command/reply",
    "Reply-Text": "+OK"
}
```

For example API call execution with Bgapi supports a job_uuid parameter which will be the value of the Job-UUID header field for the related BACKGROUND_JOB events.

```
 public ESLevent Bgapi(string cmd, string arg, string job_uuid)
```

How can the same achieved for the dialplan applications like playback?

I have checked if maybe it is hidden by the Managed Wrapper, but the esl_execute function in esl.c (which is used by the wrapper's ExecuteAsync method) doesn't seem to support this either:

```
ESL_DECLARE(esl_status_t) esl_execute(esl_handle_t *handle, const char *app, const char *arg, const char *uuid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation of sendmsg](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_event_socket#mod_event_socket-sendmsg) the `Event-UUID` header value is designed for that purpose.
The `esl_execute` function in the API uses `esl_send_recv` to send a self composed `sendmsg` message, but unfortunately it does not provide a way to set this field.
One way to go is to compose a similar `sendmsg` message which contains the `Event-UUID` field and send it via `esl_send_recv`.

For example with Managed ESL:

```
public void ExecuteApplication(ESLconnection conn, string application, string appParams, string uiid, string jobid)
{
    var header = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"call-command", "execute"},
        {"execute-app-name", application },
        {"execute-app-arg", appParams },
        {"loops", "1" },
        {"Event-UUID", jobid },
    };
    string newLine = "\n";
    var cmd = $"sendmsg {uiid}{newLine}" + string.Join(newLine, header.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}"));
    var e = conn.SendRecv(cmd);
    ...
}
```

So the message to be sent will have the following form:

```
sendmsg bb2652fa-467c-44a1-a2f0-0f5e4363e2f3
call-command: execute
execute-app-name: playback
execute-app-arg: d:\vox\sample.vox
loops: 1
Event-UUID: play command id 369
```